# Steps to analyze web server performance for only one Ip

Tags: web-server, performance, ip, iis-7.5

We have a 2008 server, hosting 40 domains. All of our projects are developed in asp.net and using iis 7.5 in our server. Nearly 35 of these domains are sharing one IP and the other 5 is sharing another Ip. Everything was fine till 4 days ago. Then one of our Ips (shared with 35 domain) began to serve very slowy. Wep pages are hangs while loading.  The interesting thing is the other web pages sharing the other IP are fine, they are loading in a normal speed.

we checked the logs of http.sys, but found nothing different. We checked iis logs and find nothing.

Can anyone tell us the ways or steps to follow to find the problem ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried enabling Failed Request Tracing?  You can set it to trace requests that exceed a certain time to execute.  Additionally, you could enable ASP.NET tracing once you narrow it down to a single page.

Comment: Yes, we tried Failed request tracing. We checked for 4 seconds. In the logs it says it took more than 4 seconds. But from the beginning to  the last GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER ends in 1 seconds. Also the last buffer ends with "trucated" means that there will be another buffer, but nothing appears. Also in some examples it ends in 2 seconds, sending the last buffer ending with html close tag(</html>), but it writes it is more than 4 seconds. We did not understand why it writes 4 seconds. does it mean there is another step but it did not completed yet ?

Comment: You may need to increase the max size of the failed request log to see the whole log: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/traceFailedRequestsLogging

Comment: Did anybody make any changes to the server or DNS configs or recode any pages? Add any modules? The two stable data on tracing it down I would use are: 1. Anything specific to that domain/site and 2. Something must've changed.